# Achieving transition effects within modal in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a simple modal which has a next button.

In this modal I first display contents within

```
<div ng-show="step1"></div>
```

Upon clicking the next button, I display different contents in 'step2" which is in the same modal.

Hence the overall modal contents looks something like..

```
<div class="modal-body">

  <div ng-show="step1">
    This is step 1
  </div>

  <div ng-show="step2">
    This is step 2
  </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="next()" ng-show="step1">Next</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="prev()" ng-show="step2">Previous</button>

</div>
```

I would like to achieve some transition effects when the user clicks on the enxt button i.e before switching over to contents from step2.. some kind of animation should occur.

At this point i have no clue where to get started.. any help will be appreciated.

Plnkr available here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/eWy6XA1U4GCWr1cK22hH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to add  ['ngAnimate'] dependency on your module then add class to your ng-show element with the help of that class you need to provide css:-
```

Here is plunker update :- http://plnkr.co/edit/PkdUxImq69s910etTy5U?p=preview